# Is there a way to run Angular app on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: angular, raspberry-pi

I'm speaking about Angular (2+).
When I opened the app in Raspberry Browser I just see a blank page.
Will installing another browser help?

Comment: yes it's possible. Whether installing another browser will help depends entierly on which browser you currently use.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no errors in the code, it depends only on the browser engine.

You can check the current browser support here: [browser-support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17580507)

Comment: This is not a "link-only answer", the answer is that it depends only on the browser. Furthermore frameworks compatibilities change quite often, so it makes no sense to copy paste the current compatibility here. I really don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ng build` to make your *index.html*, be sure to put the right `base-href`.

See [angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)